# Hibernate error :cannot parse configuration file

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, configuration

Hi I am new to java I am trying to do hibernate in eclipse this is my configuration file **Hibernate.cfg.xml** I edited it in note pad and copied it my app

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>  
    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SqlServerDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=empDb;instanceName=MSHassan"/>  
        <property name="connection.username">hmohamed</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">Kocroc1234</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver</property>  
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am getting error Cannot parse configuration file Hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Please, it's 2014 - use annotations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
<property name="connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=empDb;instanceName=MSHassan"/>
```

to:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=empDb;instanceName=MSHassan</property>
```

The former variant is valid for JPA (in persistence.xml), while the latter is Hibernate cfg specific.

Comment: I made change but still get ....jdbc ....class not found  I have added sqljdbc4.jar to jar files and set the classpath  to  its location   classpath  c:\temp\sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: @kobosh, if you add the JAR file to classpath in eclipse and then running the program from eclipse itself without deploying the code to any server then you will not get any exception. Please add more details on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's a different question. Mark this one as answered and ask a new one regarding your new exception.

Comment: but a lot needed to make it work! first   add both  jdbc.jar to classpath and to build path and  added sqljdbc_auth to path and sqljdbc_auth.dll to jdk directory and  used sql configuration manager to enable tcp/ip and assign port 1433 and it is important to create the database and also add eclipse to firewall

Comment: I never attempt to configure projects in my IDE. I always use the project build tool, like Maven.